# Getting an error of the form "operator<< must take exactly one argument" when overloading operator<<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the following code for a `BigInt` class and I'm trying to overload `operator<<`:

```
class BigInt
{
private:
    int numDigits;
    char vals[];

public:        
    friend std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& os , const BigInt &param );
};


std::ostream& BigInt::operator <<( std::ostream& os , const BigInt & param )
{
    os <<" number of the bits is " <<param.numDigits << " and it`s   valeuris" <<param.vals<<"\ n ";
    return os;
};
```

I keep getting this error:

> xxxxx must take exactly one argument.

I have searched a lot on this error. I know that I should make `operator<<` a friend function in class or declare it out of class, and I also took care about the return of operator `<<`. It is so strange that either way I'm getting an error.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Also `char vals[];` is an array of unspecified size, that's probably not what you want.

Comment: The definition has a "BigInt::" too many.

Comment: @molbdnilo that`s the problem, ty :p

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ   I see, thank you so much   :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the issue here is that you're (probably unintentionally) mixing and matching two different approaches.

When you write

```
friend std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& os , const BigInt &param );
```

inside of the class definition, you are saying that there will be a *free function* named `operator <<` that takes in an `ostream` and a `BigInt`. When you write

```
std::ostream& BigInt::operator <<( std::ostream& os , const BigInt & param )
{
    ...
};
```

you are defining a *member function* of `BigInt` named `operator <<` taking two arguments. Those two arguments, combined with the implicit `this` pointer, adds up to three arguments - more than you intended. Note that although this function is called `operator<<`, it's *not* the `operator<<` you declared as a `friend` in the class definition.

To fix this, you have a few options. First, when you define `operator<<`, you can omit the `BigInt::` prefix, which will fix things. Alternatively, combine your implementation with the `friend` definition inside the class definition:

```
friend std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& os , const BigInt & param )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: it works! Thank you so much! I didn`t really understand  'BigInt::'   :p

Comment: The out-of-line member function definition is illegal anyway, that can only happen if there had been a declaration inside the class definition (which would have raised the error at that point)